# Remove MathJax support on meta

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, meta, latex

As you may or may not know, [we briefly had MathJax support on our main site](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5024/20469). However, [it caused all sorts of problems and was removed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5056/20469). For whatever reason, MathJax support was not removed on meta. While this doesn't affect typical questions posted on meta, it causes issues in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) when users write challenges that have embedded formulas which render nicely in the Sandbox and don't render at all once it's on main. More importantly, causes issues with [snippets](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5043/20469) and [code blocks](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7068/20469).

It doesn't make any sense to have MathJax here and not on the main site, thus I believe MathJax support should be removed on meta. (At least until MathJax support is reinstated on the main site, if it ever is.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, who handles feature requests on beta sites? The same devs from Meta.SE?

Comment: Do I downvote the question if I disagree with the claim, or wait for answers?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ If you disagree you should post an answer to that effect.

Comment: @cat SE developers see all requests across all meta sites, including Meta.SE and per-site metas for beta sites.

Comment: Cool, thanks Alex.

Comment: @cat It depends on what's being requested. There are some things that moderators can deal with and some that Stack Exchange developers or community managers have to deal with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the intrepid Stack Exchange community manager [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) graciously took care of this for us. See the unrendered MathJax below.

$$ \sqrt{2} $$

Thanks so much, Shog!

Comment: Wow. That's probably the fastest response to a request. Ever.

Answer (score 7):

## Yes, but try to fix MathJax ASAP

Obviously, why have MathJax on meta (and sandbox) if it is really not going to help us on the real site? It provides no help, and can confuse users new to the sandbox. Thus, MathJax only on Meta is a detriment to our site.

However, just imagine how great it would be to *have* MathJax! Now, there are problems with it and this site's compatibility. Is anyone doing anything to fix that? Here are some posts that would IMO benefit from MathJax:

- [Prime polynomials](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/48037/prime-polynomials)
- [Implement hyperexponentiation/tetration without the use of '^'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5562/implement-hyperexponentiation-tetration-without-the-use-of)
- [Length of String Using Set Theory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25642/length-of-string-using-set-theory)
- [XOR multiplication](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50240/xor-multiplication) (the latter part)
- [Solve a System of Linear Equations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22573/solve-a-system-of-linear-equations)

(Maybe not the time and place for that latter portion. I can remove it if it is off-topic.)

Comment: I think most people here agree that MathJax would be awesome to have on main once the kinks are worked out. The only problem is that it requires dedicated SE developer time, and I'm sure this is nowhere near the top of their priority list. ;)

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't know, thanks :D